# Accessing values in HttpServlet in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt

I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemIterator

though I have added **commons-io 1.2 jar** and **commons-Fileupload 1.2.1 jar** in my buildpath.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an incompatibility between the file-upload version you're using and the servlet.jar you have on your server.

I can't tell you if it is between the "commons" jars or between the server jars and "commons".

Anyway, I suggest you use a maven (or gradle even better) project at least to get your jars in a consistent way. If your project is not ready, you can still pack your application as a war and get the correct jars from the zipped output fil of your maven compiling.